# Can I init static global variable with openmp?

Tags: c++, openmp

I want to use openmp to parallelize my program. But on some devices it will trigger __kmp_abort_process.
Openmp produced the following log .And it's quite hard to reproduce.

```
OMP: Error #100: Fatal system error detected.                                                                 
OMP: System error #1: Operation not permitted.
```

I found from the openmp source code that a "fatal system error" will only occur when openmp init env and set thread affinity.

I extracted the part of the code that I was most suspicious of.Here is my simplified pseudocode. I init a static global variable with openmp and set thread affinity manually.

```
#include <omp.h>

int test(){
  int num_threads= getFromCpuInfo();
  std::vector<int> cpu_ids = getBigCoreCpu();
  omp_set_dynamic(0);
  // set affinity for each thread
  omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);

#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    setSchedAffinity(cpu_ids);  // this func call syscall(__NR_sched_setaffinity,...);
  }
  return num_threads;
}

static const int thread_num = test();

int main(){
  printf("thread_num  %d", thread_num );
}
```

Since this problem is not easy to reproduce, I am not sure if it has been fixed. Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: What about your OS and compiler?

Comment: Most of crash happend at Android 8.1.0,level 27 but Also at Android 9.0,Android 6.0.1 etc.  compiler is ndk  20b                                                                                                              [     0]  Android (5220042 based on r346389c) clang version 8.0.7 (based on LLVM 8.0.7svn)
 [   108]  GCC: (GNU) 4.9.x 20150123 (prerelease)

Comment: OpenMP depends on implementation related to OS and compiler.

Comment: Which language? C and C++ have quite different rules in this area.  The example code is C++, so is that what you're actually using?

Comment: I don't know whether this is permitted, but it seems unnecessarily risky either way. If the goal is just to cache the number of threads, then `static auto thread_num() { static auto num = test(); return num; }` used as `thread_num()` instead of `thread_num` will do fine without any dynamic initialization before `main` is entered. (Also is `static` there really intended? Do you want to repeat the initialization for each translation unit using it? Maybe you want `inline` instead?)

Comment: It‘s a C++ program.

Comment: Yes , I try to use static function instead of global static variable .But I am not sure whether it can cause " OMP: Error #100: Fatal system error detected. OMP: System error #1: Operation not permitted."

Comment: Possibly related: [Can threads be safely created during static initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1445141/580083). It's about MSVC, but the same problem may hold for other implementations as well.